# How do I vectorized these two numpy operations without using for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

there is an operation in numpy I've found hard to implement without looping

That operation is that I have two inputs: `beta,x`

`beta.shape = (M,N,K)` and `x.shape = (I,K)`

The operation I'm interested in can be done using for loop as follows

```
result = np.zeros((M,N,I,K)) # buffer to save my operation results
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
         beta_ = beta[m][n] # has shape (K,)
         result[m][n] = x * beta_
```

Let tricks here that I can do without loops so that the whole operation can be computational efficient ?

Comment: Look into `np.einsum()`

Comment: @norok2 thanks for the reply; are u referring to solve the second problem ?

Comment: @Ruzihm; thanks you can delete the first question but keep the second one

Comment: Taking advantage of broadcasting: `result = beta[:,:, None, :] * x`.  There's no summation, so `einsum` isn't needed (though it works fine).

Comment: For the deleted part of the question, `beta.transpose(1,0,2)` will switch the first 2 dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks; it solves my problem!

Comment: @hpaulj that's a good answer, could you write an answer and explain a little more about the `None` index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're interested in multiplying the elements across the common K dimension, and keeping the results along the remaining dimensions.

This means you can use `np.einsum` using the dimensions of beta, x, and the shape result you're interested in like `'mnk,ik->mnik'`:

```
import numpy as np

M = 4
N = 3
I = 7
K = 6

beta = np.arange(M*N*K).reshape(M,N,K)
x = np.arange(I*K).reshape(I,K)

result1 = np.zeros((M,N,I,K)) # buffer to save my operation results
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
         beta_ = beta[m][n] # has shape (K,)
         result1[m][n] = x * beta_


result2 = np.einsum('mnk,ik->mnik', beta, x)

print (np.array_equal(result1,result2))
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Not part of the question but while talking about `np.einsum`... If you want to sum across any of these dimensions, you can omit it from the end dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

M = 4
N = 3
I = 7
K = 6

beta = np.arange(M*N*K).reshape(M,N,K)
x = np.arange(I*K).reshape(I,K)

result1 = np.zeros((M,N,I,K)) # buffer to save my operation results
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
         beta_ = beta[m][n] # has shape (K,)
         result1[m][n] = x * beta_
result1 = result1.sum(axis=1)


result2 = np.einsum('mnk,ik->mik', beta, x)

print (np.array_equal(result1,result2))
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and the explain of `np.einsum`

Comment: `np.einsum` is absurdly versatile. Definitely something handy to learn if you do a lot of tensor math.